# Is it possible to run an Android emulator without setting up Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to run an Android emulator without setting up Eclipse. I'm working with a contractor that has provided me with the .apk file.I was hoping I could run it without setting up a whole testing environment.

Comment: yes you can manually start the avd from sdk installation folder.. You will find AVD Manager there

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html. Check the link has details regarding the emulator. You can start emulator from command line

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no relationship from Eclipse and Android emulator other than the launcher icon.
You can even run the emulator as a stand-alone application, there's no even need for android SDK.

Comment: Can i download just the Emulator without the SDK, could you provide a link?

Comment: Search for "Get just the command line tools" in https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK tools are completely separate from Eclipse. You can simply download them from Android's website and run the AVD Manager.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to install apk on emulator simply start emulator and type in console

```
adb install path/to/apk/file.apk
```

You can find adb tool in

```
<android_sdk_path>/platform-tools/
```